# In Jasmine, how to test service response against static data

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

In angularJs app, I want to test the aboutService in jasmine. The About service returns data in the following format:

```
var companyObject = [{"CompanyName": "A", "Contact Number" : "123456789"}, {"CompanyName": "B", "Contact Number" : "1234567899"}]

angular
    .module('TestModule')
    .factory('aboutService', aboutService); 

    aboutService.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$http'];

    function homeService($rootScope, $http) {
        function getAboutData() {
            return $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: API URL,
            })
            .then(getAboutDataSuccess);

            function getAboutDataSuccess(results) {
                return results;//Data about company telephone contact number in array
            }
        }

        var aboutService = {
            getAboutData: getAboutData,
        };
    }
```

In aboutServiceSpec, I want to test if the data returned by API i.e an array length is greater than 0 and is equal to  is equal to a variable `companyObject`

I have tried the following code with Jasmine, but it does not works.

```
    describe("Service: aboutService", function () {

        var aboutService, $httpBackend, $rootScope, response;
        var companyObject = [{ "CompanyName": "A", "Contact Number": "123456789" }, { "CompanyName": "B", "Contact Number": "1234567899" }]
        beforeEach(module('TestModule'));

        beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, _aboutService_, _$rootScope_) {
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            aboutService = _aboutService_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        }));

        it('Should get about details of comapny', function () {
            $httpBackend.expectGET('URL');
            //Donot know how to go forward from here
        });
    });
```

Comment: use $httpBackend

Comment: @DanielA.White: I tried the `$httpBackend` as I mentioned in the question. But not sure how to go forward with it. Can you explain a bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('URL').respond(companyObject);
aboutService.getAboutData().then(function(result) {
    expect(result).toEqual(...); //or whatever expectation you want to test
});
$httpBackend.flush();
```

EDIT What this code does is the following:

1. `$httpBackend.expectGET(...).respond(...)` defines an *expectation*
   of what requests the code under test and mocks the response to that
   request
2. The expectations go to a `.then` block chained to the
   service returned by the promise (at this point, the promise of the
   `$http` request is not resolved yet)
3. `$httpBackend.flush()` resolves
   the promise with the mock object specified earlier (only now are the expectations in the `.then` block fired). It also has the
   side effect of invalidating the test if the expected request has not
   been made

Comment: Can you give some additional explanation of ***why*** this is the solution?

Comment: @crizzis : $httpBackend.expectGET('URL') **does not make a call to service actually**, but just returns a static object. And then we test this static object against another static condition.  So infact we are not testing anything.

Comment: Not really. We are testing *the very fact* that `aboutService.getAboutData` returns whatever the call to `$http` returns (it could very well make a call to `$http` and then not return anything, in which case the test would fail). And, more importantly, we are verifying that a `$http` request is being made *at all* (otherwise, `$httpBackend.flush` would fail). Obviously the test is 'dumb', but so is the method - it does not perform any real logic

Comment: Also, '$httpBackend.expectGET('URL') does not make a call to service actually' - of couse not. If it did, it would be an integration test (not a unit test)

Comment: crizzis - Now I got the point. Thanks for the detailed explanation